# Error when I try to authenticate through Facebook with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, facebook-oauth

I followed Ryan Bates Omniauth Part1 railscats http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1 . I put twitter and Facebook authentication with their secret numbers and when I try to authenticate through Facebook (auth/facebook) I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

And when I try to authenticate through twitter (auth/twitter) I get this 401 Unauthorized response. I don't know how I can correct it

Thanks I corrected entering `http://127.0.0.1:3000` in twitter URL callback field and in facebook my website field. But now when I try to authenticate with facebook I get this error:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
>
> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed

How can I solve it? I solved putting `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` in development.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error appears when your server runs on http protocol. You need to add this piece of code in your_project/script/rails before APP_PATH

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rails/commands/server'
require 'rack'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

module Rails
    class Server < ::Rack::Server
        def default_options
            super.merge({
                :Port => 3000,
                :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
                :daemonize => false,
                :debugger => false,
                :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
                :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
                :SSLEnable => true,
                :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                       File.open("/path_to_your/privatekey.pem").read),
                :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                       File.open("/path_to_your/servercert.crt").read),
                :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]]
            })
        end
    end
end
```

To generate self-signed certificates read this tutorial http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html (steps 1 to 4) or this [www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html)

After updating your rails script change the url from `http://127.0.0.1:3000` to `https://127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: Thank you very much!! I corrected it puting OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE in development.rb in development.rb, but I think it is a better to create a ssl secure connection.

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem fairly often with Twitter in development.

The issue is likely your callback url in your app settings.  Try setting it to:

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

And try again.  If it doesn't work from `http://localhost:3000` then try it from `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

The problem with Facebook is also likely to be the callback URL in the app settings.  For Facebook, my `site url` setting is: `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Thanks with twitter I correct it but with facebook no. In FAcebbok appa options where I have to put http://localhost:3000/ ??

Comment: I've also had problems in the past using Webbrick.  I'm not sure this is the answer here, just buyer beware.  I switched to thin, gem 'thin' in Gemfile, then rails -s thin.